# Abrir archivo DOCX con Apache POI en fuentes Java en un contenedor de Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-poi, java-11

Estoy abriendo un fichero .docx con Apache POI(3.10) para poder tomar variables y reemplazarlas para poder guardar un archivo nuevo, todas estas pruebas las hice con SpringBoot y Apache POI, generando un resultado satisfactorio de forma local.

Al momento de querer pasar estas fuentes a un VPS con una imagen Docker es cuando tengo el problema.

El error que arroja es el siguiente,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cuando la librería intenta abrir la ruta encontrada con el fichero.

```
File resources = new File("src/main/resources/PlantillaFamiliaNO.docx");
String resourcesAbsolutePath = resources.getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(resourcesAbsolutePath);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(file));  //Acá se cae
```

Y de esta forma tengo el Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD . ./src/main/resources/
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 5003
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes no es provocado por el contenedor, para entender el error hay algunas consideraciones que se deben explicar primero cuando se trabaja con un `IDE`, los `proyectos JAVA` pueden ejecutarse de 2 formas empaquetados `jar o war` o `explotados o expandidos`, una forma simple para entender la diferencia es imaginar que los `jar o war` son un archivo `zip` mientras que los `expandidos` son proyectos que ejecutan el compilado sin empaquetar o comprimir.

Los IDEs por lo general ejecutan el proyecto `expandido` esto quiere decir que tienes todo un sistema de archivos y carpetas físico que es mas conveniente para llevar un control del Código fuente y el compilado, pero al ejecutar el proyecto en el contener lo ejecutas desde el `jar` por eso el archivo `PlantillaFamiliaNO.docx` no tiene un `Path Absoluto` y tienes el error `zip file is close` porque lo quieres obtener desde dentro del proyecto `jar`, este mismo caso se puede replicar en tu ordenador si ejecutas el proyecto jar desde la consola.

Otro error que tienes derivado de ejecutar el proyecto desde el `jar` es que la clase `java.io.File` trabaja con archivos físicos no con archivos `comprimidos`, las opciones que tienes son:

1. Cambiar de `java.io.File` a `java.io.InputStream` de esta forma leerias el archivo y pasarías una copia en memoria con la que Apache POI puede trabajar.

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(getClass().getResourceAsStream("PlantillaFamiliaNO.docx")));
```

Tendrías la limitante que no puedes guardar el archivo word dentro del jar porque lo que tienes es una copia en memoria, teniendo que guardarlo fuera del jar.

2. La forma que te recomendaría es leer el archivo de forma externa al proyecto y que lo copies como recurso dentro del contenedor de esta forma podrás leer y editar sin mayor complicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración, según tus recomendaciones pude solucionar el problema, saludos.

Comment: @JorgeMartiniSchwenke que bueno que te haya funcionado, si esta fue tu repuesta recuerda marcarla para que tu pregunta se anote como resuelta y de visibilidad a otros desarrolladores que  tenga el mismo problema.